I want the x-axis label to set the color according to the ONTOLOGY classification, so I use geom_text() to add the label
I want the x-axis label to set the color according to the ONTOLOGY classification, but axis.text cannot complete such an operation, so I hide the original x-axis label and use geom_text() to add the label, but it seems that this can only be displayed It’s inside the icon. Is there any solution? Thank you.
# set color
ontology_colors <- c("BP" = "#339970", 
                     "CC" = "#ff6633",
                     "MF" = "#9999ff")
plot<- ggplot(data = eGO_top10, aes(x = Description, y = enrichment_score, fill = ONTOLOGY)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f", enrichment_score)),  # 显示两位小数的y值
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.4), vjust = -0.3,size = 2) + 
  geom_text(data = eGO_top10, aes(x = Description, y = 1, label = Description, color = ONTOLOGY),  
            angle = 75, hjust = 1, vjust = 10, size = 3.5, position = position_nudge(y = -0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = ontology_colors) +
  scale_color_manual(values = ontology_colors)+
  # facet_wrap(~ ONTOLOGY, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1) +  # 按照ONTOLOGY分类
  facet_grid(~ ONTOLOGY,scales = "free_x", space = "fixed", margins = FALSE) +  
  labs(x = "", y = "Enrichment Score", fill = "ONTOLOGY",title = "") +  
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "white"),
        # axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0,"cm"),
        plot.margin = margin(1,0,0,1,"cm"),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))  

ggsave("GO_barplot_Enrichment_Score.tiff", plot, width = 10, height = 8, units = "in", dpi = 600)

so strange
I want to make it look like this

Welcome to SO! You might have a look at the ggtext package which allows to achieve your desired result using the axis text and which would be my preferred option. You might also try with + coord_cartesian(clip="off") to prevent the labels from being clipped off. For more help please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Another option is to use the ggtext package for this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
